# jQuery cycle: generating pager thumbnail when cycling divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm cycling through dynamically generated divs that have a markup like this:

```
<div class="slider">

        <div class="servicesslider">    
               <a href="link1">
                <div class="slidertext">
                   <h1 class="sliderhead">Text1</h1>
                    <p>Body copy</p>
                </div>  
        <img width="450" height="270" src="imglink" class="attachment-front-page-services wp-post-image" alt="alt" title="title" />                     
                </a>

        </div>



       <div class="servicesslider"> 
          <a href="link2">
             <div class="slidertext">
            <h1 class="sliderhead">Text2</h1>
            <p>More body copy.</p>
             </div>
          <img width="450" height="270" src="imglink" class="attachment-front-page-services wp-post-image" alt="alt" title="title" />
           </a>

 </div>
```

I have it set up with the pager function which generates a 1, 2, 3, 4 etc links for each div. I'm trying to follow the advanced pager demo which generates a thumbnail for each slide (seen here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html )

My jQuery looks like this but the callback function breaks the effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.slider').cycle({
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    timeout: 4000,
    pager:  '#nav' 
    // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>'; 
        }
});
});
</script>
```

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/txhPK/6/

The issue is I can't get the pager to work or generate thumbnails using that technique. I imagine it's because in the demo they are cycling through just images, so grabbing the img src of the slide is easy, in my case it needs to get the image src from within a div. I'm just wondering how to achieve this.

Comment: If the answer below helped I'd appreciate you marking it as the answer or providing feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a modification and search for the image. Assuming the images always have the same class and you need only one here is the code.

```
$('.slider').cycle({
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    timeout: 4000,
    pager:  '#nav' 
    // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + $('img.wp-post-image:eq(0)',slide).attr('src') + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>'; 
        }
});
```

Similar JSFiddle Example: Similar Example
http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/vKG55/1/